# vba - how to go to next interation in loop when error

Tags: vba, for-loop, error-handling

I have below code and I am not able to skip to the next interaction (i) when an error is found in the Vlookup formula. It gives me the error "Compile Error Sub or Function not defined"

For example, if Vlookup formula gives an error in second interaction (i=2) the code should skip next lines of code and go to the next interaction (i=3)

```
For i = 1 To 10:
   If Range("A" & i).Value = "" Then
Else

    On Error GoTo Handler

    datavalue = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("DataManipulation").Range("A" & i), Sheets("ExtractQ1").Range("A1:G1048576"), 4, False)

    Sheets("DataManipulation").Range("B" & i).Value = datavalue

Handler:
   Next i

   End If

Next i
```

Comment: If you `Dim datavalue as variant`, you can store and test it for errors with `iserror(datavalue)` -- but you would need to use `Application.vlookup()` instead of `Application.worksheetfunction.vlookup()` so that the error does not break the code. However, none of my comment matches the error you are getting.

Comment: Also, check if both of those sheets/ranges (lookup value and lookup table) exist. See if you can minimise your lookup table's range, as right now you appear to be checking at least 1 million cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `On Error Resume Next`:

```
For i = 1 To 10:
   If Range("A" & i).Value = "" Then

   Else
      On Error Resume Next
      datavalue = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("DataManipulation").Range("A" & i), Sheets("ExtractQ1").Range("A1:G1048576"), 4, False)
      If Err = 0 Then
          Sheets("DataManipulation").Range("B" & i).Value = datavalue
      End If
      On Error Goto 0 ' Reactivate normal error reporting
   End If    
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

You can exploit Application.VLookUp and check its return value against being an error:

```
dim dataValue As Variant
For i = 1 To 10
    If Range("A" & i).Value <> "" Then
        dataValue = Application.VLookup(Sheets("DataManipulation").Range("A" & i), Sheets("ExtractQ1").Range("A1:G1048576"), 4, False)
        If Not IsError(dataValue) Then Sheets("DataManipulation").Range("B" & i).Value = dataValue
    End If
Next i
```